# Possible to create and write to a file on Dropbox via API?

Tags: php, api, dropbox-api

Is it possible to create a file on Dropbox via the API and write to it directly? My current solution is to create a temp file locally, write to it, upload it and then remove the temp file.

I've only been able to find references on the Dropbox documentation to uploading files and not creating files, so I assume the above isn't possible, but would love to know if anyone has found a way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would have to read it, amend it, then re-upload. Basically imitate what you would do as a human user

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm talking more about the initial file creation, as in, there is currently no file - is it possible to create the file on Dropbox and then work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what distinction you're drawing between "creating files" and "uploading files." You can certainly create/upload a file via the Dropbox API. See [`/files_put`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put). Since you tagged this with PHP, the relevant methods in the official PHP SDK are [`uploadFile`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_uploadFile) and [`uploadFileFromString`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_uploadFileFromString).

Comment: Turns out 'uploadFileFromString' was exactly what I was looking for. To clear it up, I was seeing if there was a way to create the file directly on dropbox (the same way you can use 'fileops/create_folder' to create a folder).